# Get Folder Size on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, home-directory

I have a lot of home folders under /home/ and I would like to get the total size of each users folder in an easy to read list.

ie

1. /home/user1  100MB
2. /home/user2  24MB
3. /home/user3  54MB

etc.

Currently using something similar to 
`du -hc | grep total`

Comment: how does 'du -hc' not provide your answer already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, a merge of the answers by Ernie and Depesz is closest to what you asked for, except that it should be 'du -s /home/*/ | sort -n'.  'du -h' doesn't sort properly with 'sort -n', because it's not really a number any more, e.g. 10G sorts before 10M

another alternative, if you want to find out the total disk space used by each user regardless of whether it's in their home directory or not is to install the quota utils, enable quota accounting on the relevant filesystem(s), but leave each users' quota at 0 (unlimited).  that will tell you disk space used as well as the number of files/inodes used.

then you can just run 'repquota -a' to get a report like this:

```
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/sda8
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
user1     --   67844       0       0           7748     0     0
user2     --   21908       0       0           1742     0     0
user3     --   27212       0       0            258     0     0
user4     --   25492       0       0            328     0     0
user5     --  575536       0       0           2972     0     0
user6     --   83944       0       0           1114     0     0
user7     --  501304       0       0           3418     0     0
user8     --  760068       0       0           5011     0     0
user9     -- 1445396       0       0           1932     0     0
...
```

repquota also has a "-s" option for "human readable" output, like du's "-h".  not surprisingly, it has the same sorting problem as du -h, though.

Answer (score 6):

```
du -hcs /home/*/
```

Or, for exactly what you want:

```
for i in /home/*/; do 
    user=${i#/*/}
    space=$(du -hs "$i" | cut -f1)
    echo "${user%/} = $space" 
done
```

Comment: Well its not 'exactly what you want' if you go and change the question on me :-)

Comment: If the owner of the folder is always the user, you could replace the user= line with: user=$(stat -c "%U" "$i") and the just echo "$user = $space" --That might be a bit cleaner. If you want line numbers, you can add ' | cat -n' after 'done' or just increment a variable each time in the loop.

Comment: sorry was trying to make the formatting easy to read, thanks for your help I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to find out?

If you're looking to sort by size, try this:

```
du -s /home/ |sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

just run this:

```
du -sh /home/*
```

And you should be happy.